# JQuery serialize() method not ignoring some form controls

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I am trying to serialize a form elements to check for dirty data. It stops working when I try to include the controls that I want to ignore during serialization.

I have a form comprising of textboxes, radio buttons and checkboxes. I have to ignore - search textbox (if any) and radio buttons but include rest. This what I tried till now:

```
//this serializes all the controls, ignores my filter
//var output = $('input[name!="txtSearch"], input[type=text], input[type!=radio]').serialize();

//this serializes all textboxes including search textbox and checkbox
//var output = $('input[type=text], input[type!=radio]').serialize();

//this serializes all textboxes and checkboxes including search textbox
var output = $('input[type=text], input[type=checkbox]').serialize();
$("#result").html(output);
```

Am I missing something here? This is the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2xnFV/) that I am working on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`,` in the selector works like "or."  That means that the input can satisfy *any* condition.

```
input[name!="txtSearch"], input[type=text]
```

...will still accept `txtSearch` because it satisfies the *second* part of the selector.  In the same vein, input of any type including `radio` that are not named `txtSearch` satisfy the first one.

You can use multiple negated attribute selectors simultaneously, though.  I think you're looking for

```
input[type!=radio][name!="txtSearch"]
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2xnFV/1/

Comment: Spot On! Thanks much! And also, thanks for educating me today on `,` in the selector works like "or". I am sure people like would benefit from this answer.